# How to extract a DataFrame using start and end dates with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can we extract the `DataFrame` using start and end dates and achieve this output?

**Input**

```
id  start  end
1   2009   2014
2   2010   2012
```

**Output**

```
id  data
1   2009
1   2010
1   2011
1   2012
1   2013
1   2014
2   2010
2   2011
2   2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.id,np.arange(r.start, r.end + 1)) for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index())
df1.columns = ['data','id']
df1 = df1[['id','data']]
print (df1)
   id  data
0   1  2009
1   1  2010
2   1  2011
3   1  2012
4   1  2013
5   1  2014
6   2  2010
7   2  2011
8   2  2012
```

Comment: Start and end are dates with year.if year and month it is different output

Comment: can we minimize the logic and time complexity for this logic.df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'start': pd.date_range(row.start, row.end, freq="AS"),
            'series_id': row.series_id}, columns=['start', 'series_id']) 
           for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)

Comment: @raam I use itertuples because better performance like iterrows, but if small input DataFrame, iterrows is nice one. What is size of input df?

Comment: it have large data.The size is minimum 50k indexes.

Comment: @raam - then `itertuples` should be better here.

Comment: @raam - So solution should be `df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.id, pd.date_range(r.start, r.end, freq='AS')) for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index())`

Comment: @raam - Glad can help ;)

Comment: can we reduce or we can have different logic for this df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.id, pd.date_range(r.start, r.end, freq='AS')) for r in df.itertuples()]) .reset_index())

Comment: @jezral can you give answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907083/how-to-check-that-date-is-in-range-between-start-and-end-using-python-pandas

Answer (score 2):

create the enumeration of dates between years grouped by `['id']`. Additional reformatting of the index is optional

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
melted = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:pd.Series(np.arange(x['start'],x['end']+1)))

melted.index = melted.index.droplevel(1)

id
1    2009
1    2010
1    2011
1    2012
1    2013
1    2014
2    2010
2    2011
2    2012
```

Comment: Can we get by using date_range function

Answer (score 1):

A little bit hard to understand,I think this should be slightly faster than apply

By using `reindex` and `repeat`

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['end']-df['start']+1)).assign(year=lambda x : x['start']+x.groupby('id').cumcount())
Out[453]: 
   id  start   end  year
0   1   2009  2014  2009
0   1   2009  2014  2010
0   1   2009  2014  2011
0   1   2009  2014  2012
0   1   2009  2014  2013
0   1   2009  2014  2014
1   2   2010  2012  2010
1   2   2010  2012  2011
1   2   2010  2012  2012
```