# How to check that date is in range between start and end using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Data frame 1

id start_date end_date count
1  2018-02-01  2018-02-04 4
1  2018-02-06  2018-02-07 2
2  2018-03-05  2018-03-08 3
2  2018-03-12  2018-03-15 4

Data frame 2

id start end 
1  2018-02-01 2018-02-08
2  2018-03-01 2018-03-15
```

output is like

```
id start_date end_date count
1  2018-02-01  2018-02-04 4
1  2018-02-06  2018-02-07 3
2  2018-03-05  2018-03-08 7
2  2018-03-12  2018-03-15 4
```

Explanation for output.

id:1 from 2018-02-02 to 2018-02-08.data frame 1 does not have 2018-02-08 for count is increased 2 to 3

id:2 from 2018-03-01 to 2018-03-15.data frame 1 does not include 2018-03-01 to 2018-03-04 for that count increased to 3 to 7

count is no.of days between start_date and end_date

How can i get the solution.

Comment: Is the number of rows always 2 per id? Also, `2  2018-03-05  2018-03-08 3` in dataframe1 should be `2  2018-03-05  2018-03-08 4`? In the same way, `2  2018-03-05  2018-03-08 7` in expected output should be `2  2018-03-05  2018-03-08 8`?

Comment: No.it will have n number of per id