# Extracting a date at the end of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a column of data that is in the following format:

`bla bla bla, bla bla bla, bla bla bla, bla bla bla bla bla bla, 23/09/2012`

Is there an easy way to extract the date at the end of the string from all rows? It is in the same DD/MM/YYYY format every time.

I could split on the last , but it would be good if I could specify that I want the date in case of errors in the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771128/how-to-extract-a-data-frame-using-start-and-end-dates-using-pyhton-pandas

Comment: @Xion, I don't see how that Q&A relates to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str.extract if you are not sure about the date being at the end of the string

```
df['date'] = df['col'].str.extract('(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', expand = False)

0    23/09/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

`row.split(", ")[-1]` is the string `23/09/2012`, now you can use the `date` module to extract that into a `Date` object. And use `try`/`except` for error handling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string slicing followed by [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). For example:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].str[-10:], dayfirst=True)
```